# How can I get the size of a mysql query?

Tags: sql, mysqli

I want to make an application that can get the size of a mysql query. 
for example, an application installed in a different application server made this query "select * from table"... How can I get the size of this query from the data server side?

Comment: `mysql_num_rows`? `strlen`? You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: What do you mean by `size`?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by size? The number of rows fetched? In that case, you need to use:

```
mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

The `$result` is the ``` mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM ``table``") ```.

---

Or if you want to know the length of the returned row, you need to use `char_length`.

```
SELECT char_length(column1) FROM `table`
```

Comment: I want to know the size of the query itself... is ther such a function like this sizeOf("select * from table")

it will return the size of the result for that query.. just the size, not the result itself tnx

Answer (score 0):

You have to sum all result sets' length:

```
select sum(row_size) 
from (
  select 
    char_length(column1)+
    char_length(column2)+
    char_length(column3)+
    .... /* for every columns */
  as row_size 
  from table1
) as tbl1;
```